# MySQL Java in JTable

Tags: java, beginner, mysql, swing, jdbc

This is an assignment posted [here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs108/handouts141/20HW3DBSudoku.pdf). (Part-B)

The aim here is to create a GUI in which the user can search for and insert data into a particular table of a MySQL database.

Is this an appropriate design or is it little overkill to make so many classes. The purpose of the `DataClass` is to make it possible to later change the back end database without making changes to the other classes.
Should there be two sub-classes of `Entry`, `QueryEntry` and `InsertEntry` that have their different roles? Or would that be too much?

Please, any feedback would be really helpful.

Entry Class:

```
package assign3;
/**
 * Represents the abstraction for entries that are to be
 * added to the database or searched/queried from the database.
 * 
 * Provides methods for generating SQL statements based on the state
 * of this Entry object.
 */
public class Entry {

    /** 
     * Represents the JCombobox data which can be larger than, smaller than
     * or equal to the population given in the field.
     */
    public enum Population {
        LARGER,
        SMALLER,
        EQUAL;
    }

    /**
     * Represents the JCombobox data from the GUI, which can be exact match
     * or partial match.
     */
    public enum Match {
        EXACT,
        PARTIAL;
    }

    private String metropolis;
    private String continent;
    private String population;
    private Population populationCriteria;
    private Match matchCriteria;
//  private static final String TABLE_NAME = "metropolises";


    /**
     * Construct an Entry/criteria to be searched/queried from
     * the database. Any or all of the String parameters can be empty or 
     * null if they are not to be included in the query condition.
     * @param metropolis name of the metropolis to be included in the query,
     * can be left empty
     * @param continent name of the continent to be included in the query,
     * can be left empty
     * @param population population to be included in the query, can be left empty
     * @param populationCriteria larger than, smaller than or equal to the given
     * population parameter. Ignored if population field is empty
     * @param matchFlag should be true if the option is ExactMatch otherwise false
     */
    public Entry(String metropolis, String continent,
            String population, Population populationCriteria, Match matchCriteria) {
        this.metropolis = metropolis;
        this.continent = continent;
        this.population = population;
        this.populationCriteria = populationCriteria;
        this.matchCriteria = matchCriteria;
    }


    /**
     * An entry that is constructed when it has to be added to the database.
     * All the parameter cannot be null.  
     * @param metropolis
     * @param continent
     * @param population
     */
    public Entry(String metropolis, String continent, String population) {
        this(metropolis, continent, population, Population.EQUAL, Match.EXACT);
    }


    /**
     * Generates and returns an SQL query statement as a String. Takes into
     * account the state of the Entry object. All the properties of the object
     * that have been supplied while constructing the Entry are used to generate the 
     * statement.<br>
     * <br>
     * For example, if the Entry was created with:<br>
     * Entry e = new Entry("", "", "200000",  Population.LARGER, Match.EXACT);<br>
     * then the call<br>
     * e.getQueryStatement(metropolises)<br>
     * will return<br>
     * "SELECT * FROM metropolises WHERE population > 200000;"<br>
     * 
     * @param tableName Name of the table from which data is to be queried
     * @return SQL query statement according to the state of this object
     */
    public String getQueryStatement(String tableName) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
        if (areAllFieldsEmpty(this)) return result.toString();
        result.append(" WHERE");    

        generateQuery(this, result);
        result.append(";");
        return result.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates and returns an SQL insertion statement as a String. Takes into
     * account the state of the Entry object. All the properties of the object
     * that have been supplied while constructing the Entry are used to generate the 
     * statement. <br>
     * <br>
     * If any of the fields are empty then null is returned.<br>
     * <br>
     * For example, if the entry was created with:<br>
     * Entry e = new Entry("Mumbai", "Asia", "200000");<br>
     * then the call<br>
     * e.getInsertStatement(metropolises)<br>
     * will return<br>
     * "INSERT INTO metropolises VALUES("Mumbai", "Asia", "200000");"<br>
     * <br>
     * @param tableName Name of the table into which data is to be inserted
     * @return SQL insert statement according to the state of this object OR
     * null if any of the fields are empty
     */
    public String getInsertStatement(String tableName) {
        if (anyFieldEmpty(this)) return null;
        String result = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES("
                + "\"" + this.metropolis + "\","
                + " \"" + this.continent + "\"," 
                + " " + this.population + ");";
        return result;
    }


    /* Returns true iff any of the fields of the entry is empty */
    private boolean anyFieldEmpty(Entry entry) {
        return entry.metropolis.isEmpty() || entry.continent.isEmpty()
                || entry.population.isEmpty();
    }

    /* Returns iff all fields of the given entry are empty Strings */
    private boolean areAllFieldsEmpty(Entry entry) {
        return entry.metropolis.isEmpty() && entry.continent.isEmpty() 
                && entry.population.isEmpty();
    }


    /* Generates a query SQL statement and appends it to the given result
     * based on the properties of the given entry */
    private void generateQuery(Entry entry, StringBuilder result) {
        String populationOperator = getPopulationOperator(entry.populationCriteria);

        if (!entry.metropolis.isEmpty()) {
            result.append(entry.matchCriteria == Match.EXACT ? 
                    " metropolis = \"" + entry.metropolis + "\"" : 
                        " metropolis LIKE \"%" + entry.metropolis + "%\"");
            if (!entry.continent.isEmpty() || !entry.population.isEmpty())
                result.append(" AND");
        }
        if (!entry.continent.isEmpty()) {
            result.append(entry.matchCriteria == Match.EXACT ? 
                    " continent = \"" + entry.continent + "\"" :
                        " continent LIKE \"%" + entry.continent + "%\"");
            if (!entry.population.isEmpty())
                result.append(" AND");
        }
        result.append((entry.population.isEmpty()) ? 
                "" : " population " + populationOperator + " " + entry.population);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true iff the given object is an Entry with all properties
     * equal to this Entry object's properties.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (!(o instanceof Entry)) return false;
        Entry that = (Entry) o;

        return this.metropolis.equals(that.metropolis) &&
                this.continent.equals(that.continent) &&
                this.population.equals(that.population) &&
                this.populationCriteria.equals(that.populationCriteria) &&
                this.matchCriteria.equals(that.matchCriteria);
    }


    /* Returns the operator equivalent to the populationCriteria given */
    private String getPopulationOperator(Population populationCriteria) {
        switch (populationCriteria) {
        case LARGER: return ">";
        case SMALLER: return "<";
        default: return "=";
        }
    }

}
```

DataClass:

```
package assign3;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * A class to retrieve data from a back end SQL database.
 * Used JDBC as the connector and a MySQL database as the
 * source of the data.
 * This class doesn't store the data itself. Instead, it only
 * retrieves the data and passes it to any class that calls
 * the appropriate methods.
 */
public class DataClass {

    private static String account = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_USERNAME;
    private static String password = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_PASSWORD;
    private static String server = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_DATABASE_SERVER;
    private static String database = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME;
    private static String table = "metropolises";

    private static final String DEFAULT_STATEMENT = "SELECT * FROM " + table;

    private Connection connection;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private ResultSetMetaData metadata;
    private List<String> columnNames;


    /**
     * Constructs a DataClass object and connects to the back end 
     * database.
     */
    public DataClass() {
        columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://" + server, account, password);
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeQuery("USE " + database);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(DEFAULT_STATEMENT);
            metadata = rs.getMetaData();
            int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                columnNames.add(metadata.getColumnLabel(i));
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class Exception");
            e.getStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception");
            se.getStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves data from the database based on the given Entry object.
     * Uses the properties of Entry object to determine the conditions for
     * the retrieval query. The data retrieved is stored in the given List
     * "data". The given entry should not be null.
     * @param entry The object that holds information about conditions to be used to 
     * query the database
     */
    public void retrieveData(Entry entry, List<List<String>> data) {
        /* Clear the existing data to get new data based on the current query */
        data.clear();

        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(entry.getQueryStatement(table));

            convertResultSetToList(rs, data);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception");
            se.getStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Inserts a row into the table in the database based on the given Entry
     * object. The data inserted is based on the properties of the Entry object.
     * The given List of rows "data" is cleared and the newly inserted row is stored
     * in it. 
     * a List of Strings.
     * @param entry The object based on which a new row is inserted
     * @return returns the row index where the new row is added in the table.
     * Or -1 if row is not inserted due to invalid information given
     */
    public int insertData(Entry entry, List<List<String>> data) {
        int rowIndex = -1;

        /* Clear the existing data to get new data based on the current query */
        data.clear();
        /* List to store the single data in the row added */
        List<String> rowList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            String insertStatement = entry.getInsertStatement(table);

            if (insertStatement == null) return rowIndex;

            stmt.executeUpdate(insertStatement);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(DEFAULT_STATEMENT);
            rs.last();

            rowIndex = rs.getRow();

            for (int i = 1; i <= metadata.getColumnCount(); i++)
                rowList.add(rs.getString(i));

            data.add(rowList);

            rs.first();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("Insert Error");
            se.getStackTrace();
        }

        return rowIndex;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the column names from the database as a List of Strings 
     * @return names of the column
     */
    public List<String> retrieveColumnNames() {
        return columnNames;
    }

    /* Converts the given ResultSet to a List of rows and the given list points to it.
     * The given list should ideally be empty before this method is called. */
    private void convertResultSetToList(ResultSet rs, List<List<String>> list) 
            throws SQLException {
        while (rs.next()) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= metadata.getColumnCount(); i++)
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            list.add(row);
        }
    }

}
```

TableModel Class:

```
package assign3;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * A Table Model implementation to be used in a JTable context.
 * Uses ArrayList of rows, where each row is itself an ArrayList
 * of the data in that row.
 * 
 * The data stored in this class is retrieved from the DataClass
 * which in turn gets it from a back end SQL database.
 */
public class DBTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<String> colNames;  // defines the number of cols
    private List<List<String>> data;    // one List for each row
    DataClass dataFromDB;


    public DBTableModel() {
        dataFromDB = new DataClass();
        colNames = dataFromDB.retrieveColumnNames();
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    /*
     Basic getXXX methods required by a class implementing TableModel
    */

    /**
     * Returns the name of the column at columnIndex. This is used to 
     * initialize the table's column header name. Note: this name does 
     * not need to be unique; two columns in a table can have the same name.
     * @param the column being queried
     * @return a string containing the default name of column
     */
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return colNames.get(col);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of columns in the model. A JTable uses 
     * this method to determine how many columns it should create 
     * and display by default.
     * @return the number of columns in the model
     */
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return(colNames.size());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of rows in the model. A JTable uses this 
     * method to determine how many rows it should display.
     * @return the number of rows in the model
     */
    public int getRowCount() {
        return(data.size());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value for the cell at col and row.
     * @param row the row whose value is to be queried
     * @param col the column whose value is to be queried
     * @return the value Object at the specified cell
     */
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        List rowList = data.get(row);
        Object result = null;
        if (col<rowList.size()) {
            result = rowList.get(col);
        }
        return(result);
    }


    /**
     * Returns true if a cell should be editable in the table otherwise false.
     * @param row the row whose value to be queried
     * @param col the column whose value to be queried
     * @return true if the cell is editable
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves new data from the back end database by calling on the 
     * DataClass and updates the data in "this" object. The data retrieved
     * is based on the properties of the given Entry object.
     * @param entry The properties of this entry object relay what data needs
     * to be retrieved
     */
    public void getNewDataFromDB(Entry entry) {
        dataFromDB.retrieveData(entry, data);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }


    /**
     * Adds a new row to the back end database by calling on the DataClass.
     * The data added in the new row is based on the properties of the given
     * Entry object.
     * @param entry The properties of this entry object relay what data needs
     * to be stored in the added row.
     * @return The row index of the table in the back end DB where the new row
     * is added.
     */
    public int addRow(Entry entry) {
        int rowIndex = dataFromDB.insertData(entry, data);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        return rowIndex;
    }

}
```

Finally the GUI class:

```
package assign3;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import assign3.Entry.Match;
import assign3.Entry.Population;


/**
 * Builds and displays a GUI through which users can 
 * search for and add data to the metropolis table in a back end
 * database. The data from the database is displayed as in a
 * JTable.
 */
public class TableFrame extends JFrame {

    private DBTableModel model;
    private JTable table;

    private JButton addBttn;
    private JButton searchBttn;
    private JLabel metropolisLabel;
    private JTextField metropolisField;
    private JLabel continentLabel;
    private JTextField continentField;
    private JLabel populationLabel;
    private JTextField populationField;
    private JComboBox populationCriteria;
    private JComboBox matchCriteria;

    final static String POPULATION_LARGER = "Population Larger Than";
    final static String POPULATION_SMALLER = "Population Smaller Than";
    final static String POPULATION_EQUAL = "Population Equal To";
    final static String MATCH_EXACT = "Exact Match";
    final static String MATCH_PARTIAL = "Partial Match";

    public TableFrame() {
        super("Metropolis Viewer");

        model = new DBTableModel();

        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /* Fields and labels to be added to the top part of the window */
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        metropolisLabel = new JLabel("Metropolis:  ");
        metropolisField = new JTextField(17);
        continentLabel = new JLabel("Continent:  ");
        continentField = new JTextField(17);
        populationLabel = new JLabel("Population:  ");
        populationField = new JTextField(17);

        topPanel.add(metropolisLabel);
        topPanel.add(metropolisField);
        topPanel.add(continentLabel);
        topPanel.add(continentField);
        topPanel.add(populationLabel);
        topPanel.add(populationField);

        /* Buttons and ComboBoxes on the east side of the window */
        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
        eastPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(eastPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        addBttn = new JButton("Add");
        searchBttn = new JButton("Search");
        eastPanel.add(addBttn);
        eastPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
        eastPanel.add(searchBttn);
        eastPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        /* A panel for the ComboBoxes */
        JPanel comboBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        String[] populationOptions = new String[] {POPULATION_LARGER, POPULATION_SMALLER, POPULATION_EQUAL};
        populationCriteria = new JComboBox<>(populationOptions);
        populationCriteria.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, 28));

        String[] matchOptions = new String[] {MATCH_EXACT, MATCH_PARTIAL};
        matchCriteria = new JComboBox<>(matchOptions);
        matchCriteria.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(190, 28));

        comboBoxPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Search Options"));
        comboBoxPanel.add(populationCriteria);
        comboBoxPanel.add(matchCriteria);
        comboBoxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 80));
        eastPanel.add(comboBoxPanel);

        addBttn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Entry entry = getNewEntry();
                model.addRow(entry);
            }
        });

        searchBttn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Entry entry = getNewEntry();
                model.getNewDataFromDB(entry);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    protected Entry getNewEntry() {
        String metropolis = metropolisField.getText();
        String continent = continentField.getText();
        String population = populationField.getText();
        Entry.Population populationCrit = getPopulationCriteria(populationCriteria.getSelectedItem());
        Entry.Match matchCrit = matchCriteria.getSelectedItem().equals(MATCH_EXACT) ? Match.EXACT : Match.PARTIAL;
        return new Entry(metropolis, continent, population, populationCrit, matchCrit);
    }

    private Population getPopulationCriteria(Object selectedItem) {
        switch ((String)selectedItem) {
        case POPULATION_LARGER: return Population.LARGER;
        case POPULATION_SMALLER: return Population.SMALLER;
        case POPULATION_EQUAL: return Population.EQUAL;
        default: return null;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ignored) { }
        TableFrame tf = new TableFrame();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Connection management, and `DataClass` in general

`DataClass` is a poor name. What is the main purpose of this class? Find a better name, accordingly. In general, any name with "Class" in it is probably not a very good name for a class.

These members are immediately very suspicious:

> ```
> private Connection connection;
> private Statement stmt;
> private ResultSet rs;
> private ResultSetMetaData metadata;
> private List<String> columnNames;
> ```

That is:

- `connection`:

  - Probably the class should only ever have one `Connection`. So it should be `final`. Of course, simply adding the `final` modifier will break the class as the current constructor is written. You'll need to refactor to make it compile.
  - If you cannot obtain a connection in the constructor, the class will be useless anyway, so it should throw an exception. The bottom line is: you should be able to make this member `final`.
- `stmt`:

  - First of all, consider using a `PreparedStatement` instead. That should speed up repeated execution of the same query string.
  - I'm wondering if it makes sense to cache a prepared statement object at all. Ideally, the JDBC implementation should take care of the prepared statement pooling.
  - In short, probably this should be a local variable instead, not a member
- `rs` should be local variable, not a member
- `metadata` and `columnNames` should be `final`, just like `connection`

---

Note that printing messages and stack trace to standard output is a bad practice.
You should log instead. I'm talking about this kind of thing:

> ```
> } catch (SQLException se) {
>     System.out.println("Insert Error");
>     se.getStackTrace();
> }
> ```

#### Make things final, when possible

Make everything `final` that you can, for example all these can be final:

> ```
> private static String account = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_USERNAME;
> private static String password = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_PASSWORD;
> private static String server = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_DATABASE_SERVER;
> private static String database = MyDBInfo.MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME;
> private static String table = "metropolises";
> ```

There are many many more members in all the classes that you posted that could be final. Review the entire code and try to make all members final if possible. At the minimum, convert everything final where the build doesn't break. In cases when the build would break, consider if it makes sense to reassign the member:

- If yes, consider the possibility of making it a local variable (like `Statement`, above)
- If no, consider refactoring to make it `final` (like `Connection`, above)

#### Minor things

The semicolon is unnecessary in simple enums like this one:

> ```
> public enum Population {
>     LARGER,
>     SMALLER,
>     EQUAL;  // <- no need for this ";"
> }
> ```

---

What's up with the pointless parentheses here? Just remove them:

> ```
> public int getRowCount() {
>     return(data.size());
> }
> ```

This appears in many other places too. Review the entire code, remove pointless parentheses, they are just noise in the code.

---

This should be improved:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     try {
>         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
>     } catch (Exception ignored) { }
>     TableFrame tf = new TableFrame();
> }
> ```

like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    new TableFrame();
}
```

Because, why ignore the exception? Will the application actually function if an exception is thrown there? I doubt it. And if an exception is thrown but the code ignores it, how will you debug it?

Secondly, if you're not doing anything with the created `TableFrame` object,
then there's no point storing it in a variable.

#### Conclusion

I haven't reviewed your entire code. There might be a lot more that needs to be fixed. I suggest to apply these suggestions, and post the improved code in another question. Or you could also wait for more answers.

Comment: Hi Janos, thanks a lot for all the suggestions and critiques. Would it be a good idea to declare the `connection`, `metadata` and `columnNames` variables as `static final` and then initialize them in a `static` block immediately after?

Comment: No. Do you plan to have multiple instance of this class? If yes, then all instances will share the static fields, and you may have synchronization issues. If you won't have multiple instances of this class, then making these static won't make a difference, and it will just confuse the users of the class. Without a good reason to make these static, they should stay non-static.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks! Just one more doubt, is it OK to edit the original question with the changes made from your suggestions or better to re-post the question?

Comment: Better to post a new question, and link back to this one.